# Validation in dynamic form Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I create a validtion for a dynamic form?

```
//Controller
public function store(Request $request)
{       
    $rules = [
        'companyName' => 'required',
        'bannerName' => 'required',
        'bannerDescription' => 'required',
        'bannerURL' => 'required',
        'bannerImg' => 'required',
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'companyName.required' => 'Yo, what should I call you?',
        'bannerName.required' => 'Yo, what should I call you?',
        'bannerDescription.required' => 'Yo, what should I call you?',
        'bannerURL.required' => 'Yo, what should I call you?',
        'bannerImg.required' => 'Yo, what should I call you?',
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
}
```

And here is my view, my "name" attr are arrays cause I'll store a bulk of data to DB. Clicking on "+ Add Banner" jquery will clone div with the same 4 inputs.
If I'll remove arrays everything will work ofc, but if no I'll get the following error

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'CompanyController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('companyName') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="companyName">Company URL Address</label>    
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{old('companyName')}}" id="companyName" name="companyName" placeholder="example.com">
                                <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('companyName') }}</small>        
                        </div>

                        <hr>

                         <div data-sel-baner-box>                         
                            <div data-sel-baner-form>
                                    <div class="panel-heading"><h4 style="text-align: center">New banner</h4></div>

                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('bannerName') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="bannerName">Title</label>     
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bannerName" value="{{old('bannerName')}}" name="bannerName[]" placeholder="Name">
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('bannerName') }}</small>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('bannerDescription') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="bannerDescription">Banner Description</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bannerDescription" value="{{old('bannerDescription')}}" name="bannerDescription[]" placeholder="Description">
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('bannerDescription') }}</small>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('bannerURL') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="bannerURL">Banner URL</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bannerURL" value="{{old('bannerURL')}}" name="bannerURL[]" placeholder="URL">
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('bannerURL') }}</small>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('bannerImg') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="bannerImg">File input</label>
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="bannerImg" name="bannerImg[]">
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('bannerImg') }}</small>
                                   </div>
                               </div>

                       <a href="##" data-sel-btn-add-baner class="btn btn-primary">+ Add Banner</a>
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Company</button> 

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Any hints please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use dot notation for array input validation rules as:

```
$rules = [
    'companyName.*' => 'required',
    'bannerName.*' => 'required',
    'bannerDescription.*' => 'required',
    'bannerURL.*' => 'required',
    'bannerImg.*' => 'required',
];
```

You can see docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays).

Comment: Thanks for a reply.
I've tried to do this, but it doesn't work, I guess. Still have the same error.

Comment: @qqmydarling The way of validation is the one i've stated above, Your error is in the html view due to some empty data or something else.

Comment: (2/2) ErrorException
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/test/Test/resources/views/create.blade.php)

Comment: @qqmydarling I mean line number to be exact

Comment: It says:
in helpers.php (line 547)

Comment: @qq Then, it's difficult to understand where error exists, and I'm sure it's not the validation error

Comment: Hm, so "attrname.*" in $rules must work if my attribute name is an empty array, right?

Comment: `attrname.*` validation return false when array provided is empty, or you can use rules like `attrname => 'required', attrname.* => 'required'` since no array input is sent when no input is available in view

Comment: Ok, got you. Thanks for a help

Comment: @qqmydarling It's okay